# cd "$dir_name" && rm *, why wouyld rm * execute if the dir_name is empty?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm working through the Linux command line book and came across this section.

It's talking about the command:

```
cd "$dir_name" && rm *
```

And then says the following about it:

> This is better but still leaves open the possibility that the variable, dir_name, is unset or empty, which would result in the files in the user’s home directory being deleted.

How is that possible? If dir_name is empty then the statement should evaluate to a non-zero value i.e false and then the second command rm shouldn't be executed so why does it execute?

Comment: That's not completely true: `cd ''` doesn't move you to your home directory, you stay where you are. Following it with `rm *` is still dangerous so better use something like `[ -n "$dir_name" ] && cd "$dir_name" && rm *`

Comment: @Fravadona Ohhh I just got it, an "" is a valid value for the command so it executes and thus the test evaluates to true. Thanks!

Comment: @Fravadona : While you are right, I can not find this in the description of the `cd` command in the bash man-page. The man-page only talks about a missing directory name, but leaves the effect of an empty directory name unspecified. Do you happen to know, where this behaviour for empty directory names is defined?

Comment: @user1934428 I would say it's the result of **#5** from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html _"If the pathname is null, test if the concatenation of dot, a `slash` character, and the operand names a directory"_

Comment: @Fravadona: BTW, look at the answer by Ljm Dullaart. He claims that `cd ''` is equivalent to just `cd`, and indeed **this is true for bash**. I mistakingly made my experiment with zsh, and with zsh, it behaves like **you** said, i.e. staying in the same directory.  Using bash 5.2.15 and zsh 5.8.1 for my experiments.

Comment: @user1934428 Well, the content of environment variable `CDPATH` modifies the behavior of `cd relative_path`. I guess that LjmDullaart did an `export CDPATH=/home/ljm`, so `cd ''` does indeed move him to `/home/ljm`. Setting `CDPATH` might seem useful but I wouldn't recommend to do so, because you'll have to always use `./relative_dir` when you want to go into `relative_dir`, otherwise you might end-up in `$CDPATH/relative_dir` instead.

Comment: @Fravadona: It is true that I forget to take `CDPATH` into account, but in my experiments, both zsh and bash happened to have the same CDPATH. I can confirm that without CDPATH, bash and zsh behave the same, and in the way you described it. With the identical CDPATH, they behaved differently. So the difference is in the interpretation of CDPATH. And, I do **not** have `.` in my CDPATH (as this indeed could have an influence).

Comment: @Fravadona: Just found that if I do in zsh a `setopt noposixcd`, a `cd ''` keeps me in the current directory (despite the existence of CDPATH). I find it interesting that I have to turn **off** _posixcd_ to achieve the behaviour which you found documented in the posix standard..... Perhaps it would now be worth if you would put the effective of your research as an answer?

Comment: @user1934428 It seems like `zsh` isn't POSIX compliant for that one

Comment: @Fravadona : zsh isn't compliant at all, and does not attempt to be. I did not expect it to behave the same and just stumbled over it when I mistakingly made my first experiments with zsh (my "main" workhorse) instead of bash....

Answer (score 2):

You wrongly assume that `cd` should return a have a non-zero exitcode. It is easily verified:

```
ljm@verlaine[~]$ cd /tmp
ljm@verlaine[/tmp]$ if cd "" ; then echo yes; fi
/home/ljm
yes
ljm@verlaine[~]$
```

This proves that `cd ""` has a zero exitcode and cd-s to your home dir.

Note that may `.bashrc` contains

```
export CDPATH='~'
```

Comment: What shell is this? My bash (version 5.1.16) remains in the same directory if I type `cd ""`. It does not switch to the home directory.

Comment: @Thomas That behavior is POSIX, when `export CDPATH=/home/ljm`